# Image not returning for user profile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, user-input, next.js

I'm trying to Update user image, but whenever the username input changes the image just gets disappear.
The username is generated by default.
It works fine if the same username exists in the input value.
For eg: i have user by username generated as kmmujfli34 , even if i change a single character i am getting the error.

This is the Error i'm getting in the console.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/user/photo/kmmujfli34ss 400 (Bad Request)
```

This is my backend code for updating the profile and saving the photo

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtension = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Photo could not be uploaded'
            });
        }

        let user = req.profile;
        // user's existing role before update
        let existingRole = user.role;
        let existingEmail = user.email;

        if (fields && fields.username && fields.username.length > 12) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Username should be less than 12 characters long'
            });
        }

        if (fields.username) {
            fields.username = slugify(fields.username).toLowerCase();
        }

        if (fields.password && fields.password.length < 6) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Password should be min 6 characters long'
            });
        }

        user = _.extend(user, fields);
        // user's existing role - dont update - keep it same
        user.role = existingRole;
        user.email = existingEmail;

        if (files.photo) {
            if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Image should be less than 1mb'
                });
            }
            user.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
            user.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
        }

        user.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('profile udpate error', err);
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: errorHandler(err)
                });
            }
            user.hashed_password = undefined;
            user.salt = undefined;
            user.photo = undefined;
            res.json(user);
        });
    });
};



exports.photo = (req, res) => {
    const username = req.params.username;
    User.findOne({ username }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User not found'
            });
        }
        if (user.photo.data) {
            res.set('Content-Type', user.photo.contentType);
            return res.send(user.photo.data);
        }
    });
};
```

This is what my front end looks like

```
export const update = (token, user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/user/update`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: user
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Component

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { getCookie, isAuth } from '../../actions/auth';
import { getProfile, update } from '../../actions/user';
import { API } from '../../config';

const ProfileUpdate = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        about: '',
        password: '',
        error: false,
        success: false,
        loading: false,
        photo: '',
        userData: ''
    });

    const token = getCookie('token');
    const { username, name, email, about, password, error, success, loading, photo, userData } = values;

    const init = () => {
        getProfile(token).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
            } else {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    username: data.username,
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email,
                    about: data.about
                });
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        init();
    }, []);

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        // console.log(e.target.value);
        const value = name === 'photo' ? e.target.files[0] : e.target.value;
        let userFormData = new FormData();
        userFormData.set(name, value);
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value, userData: userFormData, error: false, success: false });
    };

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setValues({ ...values, loading: true });
        update(token, userData).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false, loading: false });
            } else {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    username: data.username,
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email,
                    about: data.about,
                    password: '',
                    success: true,
                    loading: false
                });
            }
        });
    };

    const profileUpdateForm = () => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="btn btn-outline-info">
                    Profile photo
                    <input onChange={handleChange('photo')} type="file" accept="image/*" hidden />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Username</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('username')} type="text" value={username} className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('name')} type="text" value={name} className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Email</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('email')} type="text" value={email} className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">About</label>
                <textarea onChange={handleChange('about')} type="text" value={about} className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Password</label>
                <input onChange={handleChange('password')} type="password" value={password} className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );

    const showError = () => (
        <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{ display: error ? '' : 'none' }}>
            {error}
        </div>
    );

    const showSuccess = () => (
        <div className="alert alert-success" style={{ display: success ? '' : 'none' }}>
            Profile updated
        </div>
    );

    const showLoading = () => (
        <div className="alert alert-info" style={{ display: loading ? '' : 'none' }}>
            Loading...
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img
                            src={`${API}/user/photo/${username}`}
                            className="img img-fluid img-thumbnail mb-3"
                            style={{ maxHeight: 'auto', maxWidth: '100%' }}
                            alt="user profile"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8 mb-5">
                        {showSuccess()}
                        {showError()}
                        {showLoading()}
                        {profileUpdateForm()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default ProfileUpdate;
```

*' Ignore these lines as stackoverflow needs to add some more details as most of it is code `*